# jq combine positive and negative filters with select

Tags: json, jq, negation

Given the following JSON object "test.json":

```
{
    "results": [
        {"name": "package-dev_0.0.1-dev.er56ut.pkg"},
        {"name": "package-dev_0.0.23-master.qwk89mo.pkg"},
        {"name": "package_0.9.1-dev.til39aw.pkg"},
        {"name": "package_0.3.3-master.mbw80lk.pkg"}
    
    ]
}
```

I am trying to use jq to filter for instances where the key "name" contains "dev" but does not contain "master" and output the value of "name".

Filtering for instances where the key "name" contains "dev" is fine:

```
cat test.json | jq '.results[]|select(.name|contains("dev")) | .name'
"package-dev_0.0.1-dev.er56ut.pkg"
"package-dev_0.0.23-master.qwk89mo.pkg"
"package_0.9.1-dev.til39aw.pkg"
```

But I haven't been successful in removing instances where the key "name" contains "master":

```
cat test.json | jq '.results[]|select(.name|contains("dev")) | select(.name|contains("master"))|not'
false
```

Comment: Regarding `select(.name|contains("master"))|not`: `not` produces a boolean and belongs inside the `select` filter: `select(.name|contains("master")|not)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not`, which is a [builtin](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#and%2For%2Fnot) rather than an operator:

```
.results[] | select(.name | contains("dev") and (contains("master") | not)) | .name
```

```json
"package-dev_0.0.1-dev.er56ut.pkg"
"package_0.9.1-dev.til39aw.pkg"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/i1SJlwqT9q)

Alternatively, you can collect your tests in an array and test against that

```
.results[] | select([.name | contains("dev", "master")] == [true, false]) | .name
```

```json
"package-dev_0.0.1-dev.er56ut.pkg"
"package_0.9.1-dev.til39aw.pkg"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UxKZQLtree)

Comment: Thank you @pmf, that did the trick. I had been trying to use not but had only been returning boolean values, I obviously didn't have the syntax correct.